# C++ array value printing inconsistent

Tags: c++, arrays

When I print the value of the 2D array "need", I'm getting two different results. While in the initialization loop, I print out all the array elements, as shown in the output section below. At need[0][0], the output is 7 (top right of output section, "need[i][j]:00 7").

Then outside the loop, I try to directly call this element, but this time need[0][0] returns 0.

This is for a Banker's algorithm assignment, where the resources are specified in a text file that is then parsed by my program. I think this is the only relevant code section. I'm sure this is some sort of pointers problem, but I have never been instructed on C/C++ programming and I'm just sort of figuring it out on my own.

```
// Initialize the need matrix
need = new int*[numProc];
for (int i = 0; i < numProc; i++){
  for (int j = 0; j < numResources; j++){
    need[i] = new int[numResources];
cout << "  max[i][j]:" << max[i][j];
cout << "  allocation[i][j]:" << allocation[i][j];

need[i][j] = max[i][j] - allocation[i][j];
cout << "  need[i][j]:" << i << j << " " << need[i][j] << endl;
  }
}
cout << "need[0][0]" << need[0][0] << endl;
```

This is the output:

```
  max[i][j]:7  allocation[i][j]:0  need[i][j]:00 7
  max[i][j]:5  allocation[i][j]:1  need[i][j]:01 4
  max[i][j]:3  allocation[i][j]:0  need[i][j]:02 3
  max[i][j]:3  allocation[i][j]:2  need[i][j]:10 1
  max[i][j]:2  allocation[i][j]:0  need[i][j]:11 2
  max[i][j]:2  allocation[i][j]:0  need[i][j]:12 2
  max[i][j]:9  allocation[i][j]:3  need[i][j]:20 6
  max[i][j]:0  allocation[i][j]:0  need[i][j]:21 0
  max[i][j]:2  allocation[i][j]:2  need[i][j]:22 0
  max[i][j]:2  allocation[i][j]:2  need[i][j]:30 0
  max[i][j]:2  allocation[i][j]:1  need[i][j]:31 1
  max[i][j]:2  allocation[i][j]:1  need[i][j]:32 1
  max[i][j]:4  allocation[i][j]:0  need[i][j]:40 4
  max[i][j]:3  allocation[i][j]:0  need[i][j]:41 3
  max[i][j]:3  allocation[i][j]:2  need[i][j]:42 1
need[0][0]0
```

Comment: You are recreating table rows on each cell, move 'need[i] = new int[numResources];' up, it should be in 'for (int i = 0; i < numProc; i++){' block

Answer (score 1):

`need[i] = new int[numResources];` should be before `for (int j...`

You could have avoided this by not using manual memory management, e.g.

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > need(numProc, numResources);
```

Comment: Well, that was easy :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i didn't read that carefully, but i saw your allocation

```
need[i] = new int[numResources];
```

it runs numResources*numProc times.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Initialize the need matrix
need = new int*[numProc];
for (int i = 0; i < numProc; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < numResources; j++) {
    need[i] = new int[numResources];
```

The previous line is executed numResources times for each cell need[i]. Profligate leakage of memory.
Also, it gives you zeroed memory, so of course it prints 0.!!!!

```
    cout << "  max[i][j]:" << max[i][j];
    cout << "  allocation[i][j]:" << allocation[i][j];

    need[i][j] = max[i][j] - allocation[i][j];
    cout << "  need[i][j]:" << i << j << " " << need[i][j] << endl;
```

Where are `max` and `allocation` defined?

```
  }
}
cout << "need[0][0]" << need[0][0] << endl;
```